# Swing JLabel missing characters

Tags: java, swing

So I have come across a peculiar problem.

My interface is just a single label, and a JSlider.

My code(stripped):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Broken {
    JLabel value = new JLabel();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 255, 0);
    public Broken() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                value.setText("Some Value");
                panel.add(value);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Name");
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.add(slider);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Broken();
    }
}
```

What happens is the label doesn't show up. If I resize the screen from the right to the smallest possible, suddenly the text appears, and it will stay there if I resize back to what it was. I have no idea what's happening, this truly seems like a bug to me.

Before and after resizing screenshots:

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Have you tried setting a Layout Manager for the JPanel?

Comment: OK good.  Cannot reproduce here on Windows 7, using some late model Java 7 variant.  Which version of Java is showing the problem there?  BTW - does the machine have an nVidia graphics card?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Windows 8, Java 8, and yes nVidia GeForce GT 635M

Comment: *"nVidia GeForce GT 635M"*  Make sure it uses the latest drivers.  I recall hearing of (GUI rendering) problems when it doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Updated driver, restarted, still have the problem. In any case it's clear the problem is either, windows 8, java 8, or some hardware/drivers

Comment: @AndrewThompson anyway, I need to sleep unfortunately. I'll pick up  on this tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 2):

Despite your efforts, you're not on the `EventDispatchThread` when you're creating your JLabel (or JSlider, for that matter).  To test, I subclassed JLabel just see if the code was on the EDT when it's constructor is called:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Broken {
      JLabel value = new XLabel();  // called before constructor, so not on EDT
      JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 255, 0);  // same here

      public Broken() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            value.setText("Some Value");
            panel.add(value);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Name");
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.add(slider);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Broken();
      }

      class XLabel extends JLabel {
        public XLabel() {
          super();
          System.out.println("EDT? " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        }
      }
    }
```

To fix, place the `invokeLater` call in main, so as to wrap the entire construction of your class onto the EDT:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Broken2 {
  JLabel value = new JLabel();
  JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 255, 0);

  public Broken2() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    value.setText("Some Value");
    panel.add(value);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Name2");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(slider);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Generally the proper way. Create Whole app on EDT
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new Broken2();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, and thank you for your post(+1), but it still doesn't work for me. I'm suspecting it's the driver problem mentioned by Andrew, still downloading an updated driver